# What is Vim recording and how can it be disabled?

Tags: vim

I keep seeing the `recording` message at the bottom of my gVim 7.2 window.

What is it and how do I turn it off?

Comment: To turn off vim recording for good, add `map q <Nop>` to your .vimrc file.

Comment: I can't believe you want to turn recording off! I would show a really annoying popup 'Are you sure?' if one asks to turn it off (or probably would like to give options like the Windows 10 update gives).

Comment: Related: *[How do I exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor)*

Answer (score 1301, accepted):

You start recording by <kbd>q</kbd><kbd><letter></kbd>
and you can end it by typing <kbd>q</kbd> again.

Recording is a really useful feature of Vim.

It records everything you type. You can then replay it simply by typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd><letter></kbd>.
Record search, movement, replacement...

One of the best feature of Vim IMHO.

Comment: As seen other places, it's q followed by a register. A really cool (and possibly non-intuitive) part of this is that these are the *same* registers used by things like delete, yank, and put. This means that you can yank text from the editor into a register, then execute it as a command.

Comment: One more thing to note is you can hit any number before the @ to replay the recording that many times like (100@<letter>) will play your actions 100 times

Comment: You could add it afterward, by editing the register with put/yank. But I don't know why you'd want to turn recording on or off as part of a macro. ('q' doesn't affect anything when typed in insert mode.)

Comment: Hey @Jefromi, do you know what registers are used by delete, yank and put? Or are they custom ones only accessible by vim

Comment: @Wade `"` - it's called the default register.

Comment: @N0thing What, you mean what if you wanted a recording which let you create another recording?

Comment: `and how to turn off` was also the question

Comment: Cool but wrong key, i can't recall how many billion time i want to :q to quit and it go to recording. It happen because i type q too fast and then try to redo :q and it go to recording.

Comment: A bit of dissent here: vim is OK, but the first thing I do in every environment is to `set compatible`. You know, if I wanted all those 'smart' features, I'd use emacs; I use vi for its combination of simplicity, efficiency and portability.

Comment: That q does not help. No reaction. Looking at vim I am proud for all programmers of the world that greatly moved the requirements and convenience of technology during last 40 years. Even Microsoft starts to look well in comparison.

Comment: What if you need to use the letter q in your recording? How would you use it without ending the recording?

Comment: A few people here see this as a very powerful tool, so now I'm curious: what so good about it? Can you give a specific situation where recording is useful? I'm wondering what I am missing!

Comment: @physincubus One sort of simple case is when you have some key word you want to replace in the buffer, but not every instance: it could be that only every third instance of the keyword is one you want to replace. So that would involve a pattern of something like '3nce<newtext>' repeated many many times. If you record it in register 'q', you could run 1000@q to run the sequence 1000 times and if you set nowrapscan, it can save a lot of repetition

Answer (score 116):

Type <kbd>:h recording</kbd> to learn more.

```
                           *q* *recording*
q{0-9a-zA-Z"}           Record typed characters into register {0-9a-zA-Z"}
                        (uppercase to append).  The 'q' command is disabled
                        while executing a register, and it doesn't work inside
                        a mapping.  {Vi: no recording}

q                       Stops recording.  (Implementation note: The 'q' that
                        stops recording is not stored in the register, unless
                        it was the result of a mapping)  {Vi: no recording}


                                                        *@*
@{0-9a-z".=*}           Execute the contents of register {0-9a-z".=*} [count]
                        times.  Note that register '%' (name of the current
                        file) and '#' (name of the alternate file) cannot be
                        used.  For "@=" you are prompted to enter an
                        expression.  The result of the expression is then
                        executed.  See also |@:|.  {Vi: only named registers}
```

Answer (score 66):

Typing `q` starts macro recording, and the recording stops when the user hits `q` again.

As Joey Adams mentioned, to disable recording, add the following line to `.vimrc` in your home directory:

```
map q <Nop>
```

Comment: only answer about "how to turn off" part of the question. Well, it makes recording inaccessible, effectively turning it off - at least noone expects vi to have a separate thread for this code, I guess, including me.

Answer (score 45):

It sounds like you have macro recording turned on.  To shut it off, press `q`.

Refer to "[:help recording](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/repeat.html)" for further information.

Related links:

- [smr's blog: vim :: recording](http://blog.smr.co.in/linux/vim-recording/)
- [Vi and Vim Macro Tutorial: How To Record and Play](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/)

Answer (score 31):

As others have said, it's macro recording, and you turn it off with q. [Here's a nice article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/) about how-to and why it's useful.

Answer (score 27):

It means you're in "record macro" mode. This mode is entered by typing `q` followed by a register name, and can be exited by typing `q` again.

Comment: It's actually entered by typing `q` followed by any register name, which is 0-9, a-z, A-Z, and ".

Comment: Actually, it's q{0-9a-zA-Z"} - you can record a macro into any register (named by digit, letter, "). In case you actually want to use it... you execute the contents of a register with @<register>. See `:help q` and `:help @` if you're interested in using it.