# Vim mapping to surround word with a character

Tags: vim

In my vimrc file I have the following entry to surround a word with '+':

```
:nnoremap <silent> q+ wbi+<ESC>ea+<Esc>
```

I would like to change this to surround a word with any other symbol, for example a quote, but I would not like to use another plugin or to insert one more map. I would like something like this in my vimrc:

```
:nnoremap <silent> qX wbiX<ESC>eaX<Esc>
```

where X would be the character to put around the word.

How can this be done in VIM?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea:

```
:nnoremap q :let c=nr2char(getchar())\|:exec "normal wbi".c."\eea".c."\e"<CR>
```

But I don't think that `q` is a good choice, especially for your example with quotes, because `q` starts the [extremely handy recording feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527824/1296402) from vim. The normal `q` command also does expect a second character (the recording target register) and it actually can be `"`. This will be quite confusing for you when you're on another computer or if someone else is using your vim. You should [preprend a leader](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/#using-the-leader) for `q`. With a leader:

```
:nnoremap <leader>q :let c=nr2char(getchar())\|:exec "normal wbi".c."\eea".c."\e"<CR>
```

The default leader value is `\`, but this can be changed. Note that it had to be changed before defining the mapping. You can see the currently configured leader with `let mapleader` (which prints an error message if there's no leader configured). With these statements,

```
:let mapleader=','
:nnoremap <leader>q :let c=nr2char(getchar())\|:exec "normal wbi".c."\eea".c."\e"<CR>
```

you can type `,q+` to surround your word with `+` and `,q"` in order to surround your word with `"`.

---

By the way: Your mapping doesn't work if your cursor is on the last character on line. Change the mapping to:

```
:nnoremap <leader>q :let c=nr2char(getchar())\|:exec "normal viwo\ei".c."\eea".c."\e"<CR>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer because it not only solves my problem, but also introduces me to some useful Vim syntatic and semantic constructs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin!

To surround a word with `+` signs:

```
ysiw+
```

Comment: I already knew about that plugin, but I prefer to avoid plugins to prevent conflicts between them. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Tim Pope's plugin is *super* popular. It would be probably be considered an issue/bug with the other conflicting plugin. I personally consider surround.vim to be a "must have" plugin.

Comment: Well, it may change key mappings that other plugins may defined, or not? My concern here is for me to be unaware of this kind of conflict when I install a novel plugin...