# Append keys to an earlier recording in vim

Tags: vim, automation, shortcut, key-bindings

I know what [recording in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527824/10484131) is.

Let's say I have already a recording on a register and I'm missing some more keys that I want to add to that sequence. Is there a way to append these keys to an earlier recording in vim?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using an uppercase letter will append to a register, so `qA` would continue recording the `@a` macro.

From `:help q`:

```
q{0-9a-zA-Z"}       Record typed characters into register {0-9a-zA-Z"}
                    (uppercase to append).
```

Note: this works for everything related to registers, so `"Ayw` would also append the next word to register `"a`.

Answer (score 3):

**Pasting the Macro**

You can paste your register on the current file by doing this (let's say register "a"):

```
:put a
```

If I want to delete the last word of the line and I want to erase the space before it, jump to the beginning of the line and go down one line

Original register "a":

```
$diw
```

Pasting the register

```
:put a
```

On insert mode we need insert the macro literally, so we need to use <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Note: The second <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> is necessary to capture <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Modifying the Macro**

Modifying the register "a":

```
$diwx0j
```

In the above example we just added `x0j`

**Reassigning the Macro**

Then you can make a visual selection and yank to the register "a":

```
0vg_"ay

0 ........ goes to the beginning of the line
v ........ visual selection
g_ ....... goes to the end of the line without line break
"ay  ..... copy to the register "a"
```

If you want to swich modes you can type Esc literally by typing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

You can also use "let" to set a register, in this case a register "a" to swich case of the line and go to the next line:

```
let @a="V~\<Esc>0j"
```

The let option allows you to save macros in your `~/.vimrc`, wich comes in handy for those situations where you need the macro in a daily basis.

Another advantage of using "let" to assign and reassign your macro is that you can insert special keys this way:

```
:let @a="iHello World\<Return>bye\<Esc>"
```

Is necessary to use double quotes otherwise it will not work as expected.

**Note:** The digraph `^[` is inserted by typing     <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and it represents the <kbd>Esc</kbd> literally.